# why is my function not iterating and writing all the csv data into my xml template

Tags: python, xml, csv, file, elementtree

I am writing a code that is meant to grab data from a csv file and write it into an xml template then export the file with the title as output+record number. Here is the issue, my code properly creates all the files with the correct naming, I used a couple of print statements to debug my code and my for loop loops through my csv data properly and the counter output was 15 (i have 15 rows in my csv file) so I figured this part works, I used the Element Tree library in order to write into my xml template and to save the output file a an xml file. I got stuck when I opened all the output files and realized that all of them have the same record input in them which was the first row in the csv file, I don't know where my mistake is, can someone please help me

here is my code:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET 

def Task():
    """ This Function uses an XML template and replaces certain variables (parameters)
        with data in a csv file :)"""

    CSV_File = open('records1.csv', 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8')
    tree = ET.parse('Template1.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    count = 0
    for line in CSV_File:
      x = line.split(',')
      count +=1
      print(x)
      for node in root.getiterator():
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X1':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[0]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X2':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[1]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X3':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[2]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X4':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[3]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X5':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[4]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X6':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[5]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X7':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[6] 
        XML_File= open('output'+str(count)+'.xml', 'wb') 
     tree.write(XML_File)
     XML_File.close()
```

Comment: please indent your code properly in the question, it's hard to judge what might be wrong otherwise (the easiest way is to wrap it in three backticks ``` ... ``` then you can just copy and paste it in without having to re-indent)

Comment: @Anentropic sorry I just started using this platform, I hope this is better

Comment: can you provide your xml template?

Comment: can you check if it's indented right, because currently it looks like you call `tree.write` on every iteration of the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you are editing the XML `tree` object in order to save it.
By editing its values it will work only on the first loop because after that you will not find a node with `val = 'X1'` but with `val = the_value_u_set_before`.
So you actually never match an if statement after the first loop, and at the end of it you are always saving the same tree.
Just move the parsing of the template inside the for loop

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET 

def Task():
    """ This Function uses an XML template and replaces certain variables (parameters)
        with data in a csv file :)"""

    CSV_File = open('records1.csv', 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8')
    count = 0
    for line in CSV_File:
      x = line.split(',')
      // moved the next 2 lines inside the loop
      tree = ET.parse('Template1.xml')
      root = tree.getroot()
      count +=1
      print(x)
      for node in root.iter():
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X1':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[0]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X2':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[1]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X3':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[2]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X4':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[3]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X5':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[4]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X6':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[5]
        if node.attrib.get('val') == 'X7':
           node.attrib['val'] = x[6] 
        XML_File= open('output'+str(count)+'.xml', 'wb') 
        tree.write(XML_File)
        XML_File.close()
```

Comment: This worked! thank you so much i was on the brink of insanity trying to figure it out, I also indented the tree.write line and now my code works perfectly